# Crushing small files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

We run Spark 0.9.1 on Mesos 0.17 against CDH5.  Until now, we have continued using the 'mr1' version of the CDH series so that we could run the [filecrush](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush) project on our smaller files.  For various reasons, we would like to have the freedom to upgrade to MR-2.

Do any tools exist for doing this outside of Hadoop's map/reduce?  The filecrush library we use today is non-trivial, so translating the pattern to Spark did not seem straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

MR1 code usually works with no changes (or very few) with a recompile against MR2 libraries. Does that not work? This is probably quite straightforward.

You wouldn't translate this quite directly to Spark but you can probably achieve a similar effect quite easily by mapping a bunch of files and outputting the result with a different partitioning. You may just run into the same issues as Spark is going to use HDFS and its `InputFormat`s to read your data into splits, and that is kinda where your problem is coming from to begin with.

Comment: The issue is that we run on Mesos.  As far as I am aware, MRV2 does not run on Mesos today (only Yarn).  We really want a solution to this independent of the Map/Reduce library.